# Has been a file handle opened with FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN flag?

Tags: windows, file, io, handle

There are multiple flags and attributes (`dwFlagsAndAttributes`) that can be used while a file is opened with `CreateFile()` call. One of such flags is `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN`. I am wondering, is it possible to somehow detect/guess whether a file handle has been created using this flag if the only thing you have is the handle itself and no information about its `CreateFile` parameters is available?

Comment: That's probably the **least** interesting flag you would ever need to know about. It's one that doesn't have any observable effect, other than serving as a hint to the cache manager. `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` would be way more interesting to know about, for example. Anyway, what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Sometimes an observable effect depends on the point of observation. :) An attempt of re-reading from a file opened with this flag leads to a very well observable application crash on particular platforms (depending on optimization level the underlying layer can offer seeing this flag). If, say, files are opened by a broker one cannot control, there can be a question of what algorithm to apply to process the data most effectively (let's suggest any buffering is out of solution).

Comment: There shouldn't be any way this flag could cause a crash.  That means a bug, either in Windows or (more likely) your code.  It would probably be better to identify and correct the bug than to work around it like this.

Comment: This flag does not cause a crash. Re-reading of a file opened with this flag causes the crash if the underlying layers grants the flag's request. One definitely can consider **re-reading** of a file opened with this flag **as a bug** (since this is **a violation of the promise given**) but practical problems to resolve may be pretty weird sometimes.

Comment: Rereading a file opened with `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` is not a violation of the contract. This is clearly [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx#caching_behavior): *"If an application moves the file pointer for random access, optimum caching performance most likely will not occur. **However, correct operation is still guaranteed.**"*

Answer (score 3):

You can call `NtQueryInformationFile` (or [ZwQueryInformationFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567052.aspx) from kernel mode) to retrieve a [FILE_OBJECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545834.aspx) structure. Its *Flags* member provides the information you are looking for.

Comment: This works indeed. Thank you for the information; I could not reach it by myself. Nevertheless, I would like to ensure we are talking about the same things. I do not see any FILE_OBJECT but I see that FILE_MODE_INFORMATION structure contains Mode field (ULONG) that can contain flag FILE_SEQUENTIAL_ONLY (for the CreateFile's option I am interested in) as well as flag FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING (that neutralizes the option I am interested in). Is this what you meant or have I missed something you wanted to point out?

Comment: @Mtm3.14: The `FILE_OBJECT` structure is defined in the *wdm.h* header file. The `FO_SEQUENTIAL_ONLY` flag corresponds to the `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` in the `CreateFile` call. I don't know how `FO_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` factors into this.